# Trying to find a book with people born with stones in them that gave them a special "talent"

Tags: story-identification

Trying to find this book I encountered either in the late 90s or early 2000s. The prologue was that a party of adventures killed/stole from a dragon(?) a magical stone each. Each person's stone gave them a special talent. One became a magic user, one a great sword master, and one had empathy like powers. There may have been others but I only remember these 3.

There was a caste system. These adventure's descendents were born with the corresponding stone of their ancestor and inherited the power from it. I think the magic users ruled, the sword masters were used like champions/gladiators (forced to kill on command), and the empaths we're effectively pleasure slaves.

I think the story followed a youth of each caste who didn't know about the system or their abilities, being forced to defend themselves from becoming slaves to the system.

I only got to read a little of the book with the warrior kid at a book fair when I was young. I think I skipped it back then because I had no money but now I really want to find it. Has anyone heard of this series?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: I think I just found it! (My husband was looking too).             Heir Chronicles by Cinda Williams Chima

Comment: Fantastic. Don't forget to self-answer and accept it, so that future searchers know what you were looking for

Answer (score 6):

[Heir Chronicles](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/6422668-the-heir-chronicles) by Cinda Williams Chima

> Before he knew about the Roses, 16-year-old Jack lived an unremarkable
> life in the small Ohio town of Trinity. Only the medicine he has to
> take daily and the thick scar above his heart set him apart from the
> other high schoolers. Then one day Jack skips his medicine. Suddenly,
> he is stronger, fiercer, and more confident than ever before. And it
> feels great—until he loses control of his own strength and nearly
> kills another player during soccer team tryouts.
>
> Soon, Jack learns the startling truth about himself: he is Weirlind,
> part of an underground society of magical people who live among us. At
> their helm sits the feuding houses of the Red Rose and the White Rose,
> whose power is determined by playing The Game—a magical tournament in
> which each house sponsors a warrior to fight to the death. The winning
> house rules the Weir.
>
> As if his bizarre heritage isn't enough, Jack finds out that he's not
> just another member of Weirlind—he's one of the last of the
> warriors—at a time when both houses are scouting for a player.